# Why LaTex only prints the first page of a document?

Tags: equations

I'm writing my first document with Tex and encountered problem(s) with it. At the moment I can only get the first page printed out :/ I'd appreciate enormously if anyone could help or give hints for my document attached below

```
\documentclass[a4paper,finnish,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[text={18cm,27cm},centering]{geometry}

%\usepackage{hyperref}



\usepackage{bm}
\newcommand*{\m}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\TR}{tr}
\DeclareMathOperator{\RE}{Re}
\DeclareMathOperator{\IM}{Im}
\newcommand*{\BAR}[1]{\overline{#1}}


\newtheorem{lause}{Lause}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[lause]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{esim}[lause]{Esimerkki}
\newtheorem{prop}[lause]{Propositio}
\newtheorem{seur}[lause]{Seuraus}



\pagestyle{empty}


\begin{document}
\title{MAT-33500 Differentiaaliyhtälöt -- Harjoitustyö}
\maketitle
\\
\textbf{Niina Kuittinen, 212291}\\
\\
Tehtävänannon epähomogeeninen differentiaaliyhtälösysteemi on määritelty opiskelijanumerosta riippuvien muuttujien a, b ja c avulla. Opiskelijanumerolla 212291 saadaan muuttujien arvoiksi \(a=-1\), \(b=8\) ja \(c=-7\). Sijoittamalla muuttujien arvot saadaan seuraava yhtälöryhmä.\\

    \[
    \begin{cases}
    x_1'=-1x_1+1x_5-1x_6, & x_1(0)=1\\
    x_2'=-9x_1+8x_2+x_5+6x_6, & x_2(0)=-1\\
    x_3'=6x_1-6x_2+8x_4+7x_4, & x_3(0)=0\\
    x_4'=-7x_3+8x_4+8x_6, & x_4(0)=0\\
    x_5'=7x_1-7x_2-1x_5+9x_6+sin(t), & x_5(0)=0\\
    x_6'=7x_1-7x_2+8x_6, & x_6(0)=0
    \end{cases}
    \]


Määritetään vektorit \textbf{x}, \textbf{f} ja \textbf{c} sekä kerroinmatriisi A.\\

    \[
    \textbf{x}=\begin{bmatrix}
    x_1\\
    x_2\\
    x_3\\
    x_4\\
    x_5\\
    x_6
    \end{bmatrix}.
    \]

        \[
    \textbf{c}=\begin{bmatrix}
    1\\
    -1\\
    0\\
    0\\
    0\\
    0
    \end{bmatrix}.
    \]

        \[
    \textbf{f}=\begin{bmatrix}
    0\\
    0\\
    0\\
    0\\
    sin(t)\\
    0
    \end{bmatrix}.
    \]


        \[
    A=\begin{bmatrix}
    -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -1\\
    -9 & 8 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 6\\
    6 & -6 & 8 & 7 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & -7 & 8 & 0 & 8\\
    7 & -7 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 9\\
    7 & -7 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 8
    \end{bmatrix}.
    \]

Ratkaisemalla karakteristinen yhtälö \[\(A-I\lambda\)=0\] saadaan matriisille ominaisarvot \lambda_1,2 = -1 ja \lambda_3,4,5,6 = 8\pm7i. Ominaisvektoreiksi saadaan \textbf{v_1} ja \textbf{v_2}. Matriisihtälöiden ratkaisuun on käytetty koko harjoitustyön osalta Maple-ohjelmistoa.

        \[
    \textbf{v_1}=\begin{bmatrix}
    1\\
    1\\
    0\\
    0\\
    0\\
    0
    \end{bmatrix}.
    \]

            \[
    \textbf{v_2}=\begin{bmatrix}
    0\\
    0\\
    -i\\
    1\\
    0\\
    0
    \end{bmatrix}.
    \]

Koska matriisilla ei ole täyttä määrää ominaisarvoja vaan \(alg(\lambda_1,2)=2\)] ja \([alg(\lambda_3,4,5,6)=4\), tulee etsiä yleistettyjä ominaisvektoreita. Selvitetään Jordanin ketjun avulla ominaisarvoa -1 vastaava yleistetty ominaisvektori \textbf{u} sekä ominaisarvoa \(8+7i\) vastaava kompleksinen yleistetty ominaisvektori \textbf{w}.


            \[
    \textbf{u}=\begin{bmatrix}
    0\\
    0\\
    0\\
    0\\
    1\\
    0
    \end{bmatrix}.
    \]


            \[
    \textbf{w}=\begin{bmatrix}
    0\\
    -i\\
    1\\
    0\\
    1\\
    1
    \end{bmatrix}.
    \]

Ominaisvektorien avulla voidaan muodostaa similaarimuunnosmatriisi P.\\
\\

P=\begin{bmatrix}\m{v}_1 & \m{u} & \RE(\m{v}_2) & \IM(\m{v}_2) & \RE(\m{w}) & \IM(\m{w}) \end{bmatrix} =
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 1 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0
    \end{bmatrix}.
\]

ja siis P^{-1} on P:n käänteismatriisi.
\[
P^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -1\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
    1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
    \end{bmatrix}.
\]
Nyt 
\[
e^{\Big(t\begin{bmatrix}8 & 7 & 1 & 0\\ -7 & 8 & 0 & 1\\0 & 0 & 8 & 7\\0 & 0 & -7 & 8\end{bmatrix}\Big)}=e^{8t}
\begin{bmatrix}\cos(7t) & \sin(7t) & t\cos(7t) & \tsin(7t)\\ -\sin(7t) & \cos(7t) & -t\sin(7t) & t\cos(7t)\\0 & 0 & \cos(7t) & \sin(7t)\\0 & 0 & -\sin(7t) & \cos(7t) \end{bmatrix}
\]
ja siis
\begin{align*}
e^{tA} = &P\begin{bmatrix}e^{-t} & \\ &e^{\Big(t\begin{bmatrix}8 & 7 & 1 & 0\\ -7 &8 & 0 & 1\\0 & 0 & 8 & 7\\0 & 0 & -7 & 8\end{bmatrix}\Big)} \end{bmatrix}\\P^{-1}
=& \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 1 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
e^{-t} & te^{t} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & e^{-t} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & e^{8t}\cos(7t) & e^{8t}\sin(7t) & te^{8t}\cos(7t) & te^{8t}\sin(7t)\\0 & 0 & -e^{8t}\sin(7t) & e^{8t}\cos(7t) & -e^{8t}t\sin(7t) & te^{8t}\cos(7t)\\0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & e^{8t}\cos(7t) & e^{8t}\sin(7t)\\0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -e^{8t}\sin(7t) & e^{8t}\cos(7t)\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -1\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
    1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}
\\
=&\left[ \begin{array} {ccc}
 e^{-t} & e^{-t}-e^{8t}\cos(7t) & -te^{8t}\cos{7t}+e^{8t}\cos(7t) \\ 0 & e^{8t}\cos(7t) & te^{8t}\cos(7t)-e^{8t}\sin(7t)\\ 0 & 0 & e^{8t}\cos(7t)\\ 0 & 0 & e^{8t}\sin(7t)\\
e^{-t} & te^{-t} & 0\\-te^{-t} & -te^{-t}+e^{8t}\sin(7t) & te^{8t}\sin(7t)  
\end{array} \right.\\
&\left.\begin{array} {cc}
  e^{8t}\sin(7t) & e^{8t}\sin(7t) & e^{8t}\sin(7t)\\-e^{8t}\sin(7t) & -e^{8t}\sin(7t) & -e^{8t}\sin(7t)\\-e^{8t}\sin(7t) & 0 & 0\\e^{8t}\cos(7t) & 0 & 0\\0 & e^{-t} & 0\\e^{8t}\sin(7t)+e^{8t}\cos(7t) & -e^{-t}+e^{8t}\cos(7t) & e^{8t}\cos(7t)
\end{array}\right],
\end{align*}

Jos $\m{f}:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}^n$ on paloittain jatkuva funktio, niin
alkuarvo-ongelman 
\[
\m{x}'=A\m{x}+\m{f},\ \m{x}(0)=\m{c}
\]
ratkaisu on
\[
\m{x}(t)=e^{tA}\m{c}+\int_0^t e^{(t-s)A}\m{f}(s) ds
\]
eikä muita ratkaisuja ole. Kun e^{tA} tunnetaan, voidaan tämän nojalla selvittää vektori \m{x} vakionvariointikaavan avulla. Integrointi ja sievennys on suoritettu käyttäen Maple-ohjelmistoa. Ratkaisuksi saadaan


\begin{align*}
\m{x}==&\left[ \begin{array} {ccc}
e^{-t}+te^{-t}(\frac{1}{800}-\frac{1}{32}e^{-8t}\cos(8t)-\frac{1}{32}e^{-8t}\sin(8t)+\frac{3}{100}e^{-8t}\cos(6t)+\frac{1}{25}e^{-8t}\sin(6t))\\e^{-t}-2e^{8t}\cos(7t)+te^{-t}(\frac{1}{800}-\frac{1}{32}e^{-8t}\cos(8t)-\frac{1}{32}e^{-8t}\sint(8t)+\frac{3}{100}e^{-8t}\cos(6t)+\frac{1}{25}e^{-8t}\sin(6t))\\ -2te^{8t}\cos(7t)+2e^{8t}\sin{7t}+e^{8t}\cos(7t)(\frac{143}{160000}+\frac{1}{32}te^{-8t}\cos(8t)+\frac{1}{256}e^{-8t}\cos(8t)+\frac{1}{32}e^{-8t}\sin(8t)t-\frac{3}{100}e^{-8t}\cos(6t)t-\frac{3}{625}e^{-8t}\cos(6t)-\frac{1}{25}e^{-8t}\sin(6t))\\2e^{8t}\sin(7t)-e^{8t}\sin(7t)(\frac{143}{160000}+\frac{1}{32}te^{-8t}\cos(8t)+\frac{1}{256}e^{-8t}\cos(8t)+\frac{1}{32}e^{-8t}\sin(8t)t-\frac{3}{100}e^{-8t}\cos(6t)t-\frac{3}{624}e^{-8t}\cos{6t}-\frac{1}{25}e^{-8t}\sin(6t)t-\frac{7}{5000}e^{-8t}\sin(6t)\\2e^{8t}\sin(7t)+e^{-t}(\frac{1}{800}-{1}{32}e^{-8t}\cos(8t)-\frac{1}{32}e^{-8t}\sin{8t}+\frac{3}{100}e^{-8t}\cos(6t)+\frac{1}{25}e^{-8t}\sin(6t))\\-\frac{1}{13600}e^{8t}\cos(7t)(-119e^{8t}+544\cos(6t)-408\sin(6t)-800\cos(2t)+200\sin(2t)+800-425\cos(8t)+425\sin(8t)-16000\sin(t)^2-400\sin(t)\cos(t))e^{-8t}

\end{array} \right.\\

&\left.\begin{array} {cc}
 +\frac{1}/{13600}te^{-t}(-119e^{8t}+544\cos{6t}-408\sin(6t)-800\cos(2t)+200\sin(2t)+800-425\cos(8t)+425\sin(8t)-1600\sin(t)^{2}-400\sin(t)\cos(t))e^{-8t}\\-\frac{1}{13600}(-te^{-t}+e^{8t}\sin(7t))(-119e^{8t}+544\cos(6t)-408\sin(6t)-800\cos(2t)+200\sin(2t)+800-425\cos(8t)+425\sin(8t)-1600\sin(t)^{2}-400\sin(t)\cos(t))e^{-8t}\\+e^{8t}\sin(7t)(-\frac{7}{5000}+\frac{1}{25}e^{-8t}\cos(6t)+\frac{7}{5000}e^{-8t}\cos(6t)-\frac{3}{100}e^{-8t}\sin(6t)t-\frac{3}{625}e^(-8t)\sin(6t)-\frac{1}{32}te^{-8t}\cos(8t)+\frac{1}{32}e^{-8t}\sin(8t)t+\frac{1}{256}e^{-8t}\sin(8t))-\frac{1}{13600}te^{8t}sin(7t)(-119e^{8t}+544\cos(6t)-408\sin(6t)-800\cos(2t)+200\sin(2t)+800-425\cos(8t)+425\sin(8t)-16000\sin(t)^2-400\sin(t)\cos(t))e^{-8t}\\+e^{8t}\cos(7t)(-\frac{7}{5000}+\frac{1}{25}e^{-8t}\cos(6t)t+\frac{7}{5000}e^{-8t}\cos(6t)-\frac{3}{100}e^{-8t}\sin(6t)t-\frac{3}{625}e^{8t}\sin(6t)-\frac{1}{32}te^(-8t)\cos(8t)+\frac{1}{32}e^{-8t}\sint(8t)t+\frac{1}{256}e^{-8t}\sin(8t))-\frac{1}{13600}(e^{8t}\sin(7t)+te^{8t}\cos{7t})(-119e^{8t}+544\cos(6t)-408\sin(6t)-800\cos(2t)+200\sin(2t)+800-425\cos(8t)+425\sin(8t)-16000\sin(t)^2-400\sin(t)\cos(t))e^{-8t}\\-\frac{1}{3600}(e^{-t}+e^{8t}\cos(7t))(-119e^{8t}+544\cos{6t}-408\sin(6t)-800\cos(2t)+200\sin(2t)+800-425\cos(8t)+425\sin(8t)-16000\sin(t)^{2}-400\sin(t)\cos(t))e{-8t}\\+2e^{8t}\sin(7t)
\end{array}\right],
\end{align*}
\\
Sijoittamalla ratkaisuun \(t=0\) saadaan vektori \textbf{c}, joten yhtälöryhmän ratkaisu on oikea. Alkuperäisen differentiaaliryhmän ratkaisut x_1 -- x_6 voidaan lukean edeltävän matriisin vastaavilta riveiltä. Ratkaisun stabiiliutta voidaan tarkastella niin kutsutun Lyapunovin lauseen avulla. Sen nojalla yhtälöryhmän ratkaisu on stabiili mikäli kerroinmatriisien kaikkien ominaisarvojen reaaliosat ovat negatiivisia. Koska \(\RE(\lambda_{3,4,5,6})=8\]), ratkaisu ei ole stabiili.

\eject
\end{document}
```

Comment: I get lots and lots of errors when I compile this. Try to comment out large amounts of text until you get the document to compile, even if it means reducing to just `\begin{document} \end{document}`. Then you uncomment small parts of the text at the time, debugging as you go.

Comment: At first sight it seems that you have a lot of empty lines in mathmode which causes `latex` to crash. I can't believe that you're not getting any errors.

Comment: LaTeX prints the first page very likely because it halts on some of the errors. Try to read the log output of the LaTeX run, and find the first error, correct the code, and propagate this way through the code. And btw, Welcome to TeX.SX! You may have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436).

Answer (score 6):

Once you get a TeX error you should fix that error without even thinking of looking at the pdf. If you scroll past the error TeX's error recovery almost never does anything sensible.

so

```
! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package inputenc.
```

Remove

```
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
```

then

```
! LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end.
```

Remove any `\\` that isn't in a tabular or cases or similar construct.

```
! LaTeX Error: Bad math environment delimiter.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.100 Ratkaisemalla karakteristinen yhtälö \[\(
```

You can have display math `\[` or inline math `\(` not both at same time.

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.100 ... saadaan matriisille ominaisarvot \lambda
```

math constructs like `\lambda` have to be in math mode

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.100 .... Ominaisvektoreiksi saadaan \textbf{v_1}
```

`\textbf` takes you back out of math mode into text mode so tt subscript character is not legal there. You want `\mathbf{v}_1`

Then other things, never leave a blank line before displaymath `\[` don't have `\eject` at the end.

I fixed the first few but then gave up but this runs without error:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,finnish,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[text={18cm,27cm},centering]{geometry}

%\usepackage{hyperref}



\usepackage{bm}
\newcommand*{\m}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\TR}{tr}
\DeclareMathOperator{\RE}{Re}
\DeclareMathOperator{\IM}{Im}
\newcommand*{\BAR}[1]{\overline{#1}}


\newtheorem{lause}{Lause}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[lause]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{esim}[lause]{Esimerkki}
\newtheorem{prop}[lause]{Propositio}
\newtheorem{seur}[lause]{Seuraus}



\pagestyle{empty}


\begin{document}
\title{MAT-33500 Differentiaaliyhtälöt -- Harjoitustyö}
\maketitle

\textbf{Niina Kuittinen, 212291}

Tehtävänannon epähomogeeninen differentiaaliyhtälösysteemi on määritelty opiskelijanumerosta riippuvien muuttujien a, b ja c avulla. Opiskelijanumerolla 212291 saadaan muuttujien arvoiksi \(a=-1\), \(b=8\) ja \(c=-7\). Sijoittamalla muuttujien arvot saadaan seuraava yhtälöryhmä.
    \[
    \begin{cases}
    x_1'=-1x_1+1x_5-1x_6, & x_1(0)=1\\
    x_2'=-9x_1+8x_2+x_5+6x_6, & x_2(0)=-1\\
    x_3'=6x_1-6x_2+8x_4+7x_4, & x_3(0)=0\\
    x_4'=-7x_3+8x_4+8x_6, & x_4(0)=0\\
    x_5'=7x_1-7x_2-1x_5+9x_6+sin(t), & x_5(0)=0\\
    x_6'=7x_1-7x_2+8x_6, & x_6(0)=0
    \end{cases}
    \]


Määritetään vektorit \textbf{x}, \textbf{f} ja \textbf{c} sekä kerroinmatriisi A.
    \[
    \mathbf{x}=\begin{bmatrix}
    x_1\\
    x_2\\
    x_3\\
    x_4\\
    x_5\\
    x_6
    \end{bmatrix}.
    \]
        \[
    \mathbf{c}=\begin{bmatrix}
    1\\
    -1\\
    0\\
    0\\
    0\\
    0
    \end{bmatrix}.
    \]
        \[
    \mathbf{f}=\begin{bmatrix}
    0\\
    0\\
    0\\
    0\\
    sin(t)\\
    0
    \end{bmatrix}.
    \]
        \[
    A=\begin{bmatrix}
    -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -1\\
    -9 & 8 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 6\\
    6 & -6 & 8 & 7 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & -7 & 8 & 0 & 8\\
    7 & -7 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 9\\
    7 & -7 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 8
    \end{bmatrix}.
    \]

Ratkaisemalla karakteristinen yhtälö \(A-I\lambda=0\) saadaan matriisille ominaisarvot \(\lambda_1,2 = -1 ja \lambda_3,4,5,6 = 8\pm7i\). Ominaisvektoreiksi saadaan \(\mathbf{v}_1\) ja \(\mathbf{v}_2\). Matriisihtälöiden ratkaisuun on käytetty koko harjoitustyön osalta Maple-ohjelmistoa.
        \[
    \mathbf{v}_1=\begin{bmatrix}
    1\\
    1\\
    0\\
    0\\
    0\\
    0
    \end{bmatrix}.
    \]
            \[
    \mathbf{v}_2=\begin{bmatrix}
    0\\
    0\\
    -i\\
    1\\
    0\\
    0
    \end{bmatrix}.
    \]


\end{document}
```

Comment: In general: compile often! I refuse to believe that the document has ever been compiled. I gave up where the massive `\begin{align}` blocks started around line 220...

Answer (score 2):

It is indeed a bit messy ;) Well, here is a version of your code that will compile (only the align* sections are removed because I really do not see what you want to do with those.

A few tips:

- always use the math environment "$" for vectors,
- subscripts such as "_1" must be inside a math environment
- use "mathbf" instead of "textbf" within math environment...

  ```
  \documentclass[a4paper,finnish,12pt]{article}
  % \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  % \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  % \usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
  \usepackage{babel}
  \usepackage{amsmath}
  \usepackage{amssymb}
  \usepackage[text={18cm,27cm},centering]{geometry}
  %\usepackage{hyperref}
  \usepackage{bm}
  \newcommand*{\m}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
  \DeclareMathOperator{\TR}{tr}
  \DeclareMathOperator{\RE}{Re}
  \DeclareMathOperator{\IM}{Im}
  \newcommand*{\BAR}[1]{\overline{#1}}
  \newtheorem{lause}{Lause}[section]
  \newtheorem{lemma}[lause]{Lemma}
  \newtheorem{esim}[lause]{Esimerkki}
  \newtheorem{prop}[lause]{Propositio}
  \newtheorem{seur}[lause]{Seuraus}

  \pagestyle{empty}

  \begin{document}
  \title{MAT-33500 Differentiaaliyhtälöt -- Harjoitustyö}
  \maketitle
  \section{Niina Kuittinen, 212291}
  Tehtävänannon epähomogeeninen differentiaaliyhtälösysteemi on määritelty opiskelijanumerosta riippuvien muuttujien a, b ja c avulla. Opiskelijanumerolla 212291 saadaan muuttujien arvoiksi \(a=-1\), \(b=8\) ja \(c=-7\). Sijoittamalla muuttujien arvot saadaan seuraava yhtälöryhmä.\\

  \[
  \begin{cases}
  x_1'=-1x_1+1x_5-1x_6, & x_1(0)=1\\
  x_2'=-9x_1+8x_2+x_5+6x_6, & x_2(0)=-1\\
  x_3'=6x_1-6x_2+8x_4+7x_4, & x_3(0)=0\\
  x_4'=-7x_3+8x_4+8x_6, & x_4(0)=0\\
  x_5'=7x_1-7x_2-1x_5+9x_6+sin(t), & x_5(0)=0\\
  x_6'=7x_1-7x_2+8x_6, & x_6(0)=0
  \end{cases}
  \]

  Määritetään vektorit \textbf{x}, \textbf{f} ja \textbf{c} sekä kerroinmatriisi A.\\
  \[
  \textbf{x}=\begin{bmatrix}
  x_1\\
  x_2\\
  x_3\\
  x_4\\
  x_5\\
  x_6
  \end{bmatrix}.
  \]

  \[
  \textbf{c}=\begin{bmatrix}
  1\\
  -1\\
  0\\
  0\\
  0\\
  0
  \end{bmatrix}.
  \]

  \[
  \textbf{f}=\begin{bmatrix}
  0\\
  0\\
  0\\
  0\\
  sin(t)\\
  0
  \end{bmatrix}.
  \]

  \[
  A=\begin{bmatrix}
  -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -1\\
  -9 & 8 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 6\\
  6 & -6 & 8 & 7 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 0 & -7 & 8 & 0 & 8\\
  7 & -7 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 9\\
  7 & -7 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 8
  \end{bmatrix}.
  \]

  Ratkaisemalla karakteristinen yhtälö $(A-I\lambda)=0$ saadaan matriisille ominaisarvot $\lambda_1,2 = -1$ ja $\lambda_3,4,5,6 = 8\pm7i$. Ominaisvektoreiksi saadaan $\mathbf{v_1}$ ja $\mathbf{v_2}$. Matriisihtälöiden ratkaisuun on käytetty koko harjoitustyön osalta Maple-ohjelmistoa.

  \[
  \mathbf{v_1}=\begin{bmatrix}
  1\\
  1\\
  0\\
  0\\
  0\\
  0
  \end{bmatrix}.
  \]

  \[
  \mathbf{v_2}=\begin{bmatrix}
  0\\
  0\\
  -i\\
  1\\
  0\\
  0
  \end{bmatrix}.
  \]

  Koska matriisilla ei ole täyttä määrää ominaisarvoja vaan \(alg(\lambda_1,2)=2\)] ja \([alg(\lambda_3,4,5,6)=4\), tulee etsiä yleistettyjä ominaisvektoreita. Selvitetään Jordanin ketjun avulla ominaisarvoa -1 vastaava yleistetty ominaisvektori \textbf{u} sekä ominaisarvoa \(8+7i\) vastaava kompleksinen yleistetty ominaisvektori \textbf{w}.


  \[
  \textbf{u}=\begin{bmatrix}
  0\\
  0\\
  0\\
  0\\
  1\\
  0
  \end{bmatrix}.
  \]

  \[
  \textbf{w}=\begin{bmatrix}
  0\\
  -i\\
  1\\
  0\\
  1\\
  1
  \end{bmatrix}.
  \]

  Ominaisvektorien avulla voidaan muodostaa similaarimuunnosmatriisi P.\\

  \[
  P=\begin{bmatrix}\m{v}_1 & \m{u} & \RE(\m{v}_2) & \IM(\m{v}_2) & \RE(\m{w}) &     \IM(\m{w}) \end{bmatrix} =
  \begin{bmatrix}
  1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
  1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1\\
  0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 1 & 0\\
  0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0
  \end{bmatrix}.
  \]

  ja siis $P^{-1}$ on P:n käänteismatriisi.
  \[
  P^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}
  1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -1\\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
  1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
  \end{bmatrix}.
  \]
  Nyt 
  \[
  e^{\Big(t\begin{bmatrix}8 & 7 & 1 & 0\\ -7 & 8 & 0 & 1\\0 & 0 & 8 & 7\\0 & 0 & -7 & 8\end{bmatrix}\Big)}=e^{8t}
  \begin{bmatrix}\cos(7t) & \sin(7t) & t\cos(7t) & \sin(7t)\\ -\sin(7t) & \cos(7t) & -t\sin(7t) & t\cos(7t)\\0 & 0 & \cos(7t) & \sin(7t)\\0 & 0 & -\sin(7t) & \cos(7t)     \end{bmatrix}
  \]
  ja siis

  Jos $\m{f}:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}^n$ on paloittain jatkuva funktio, niin
  alkuarvo-ongelman 
  \[
  \m{x}'=A\m{x}+\m{f},\ \m{x}(0)=\m{c}
  \]
  ratkaisu on
  \[
  \m{x}(t)=e^{tA}\m{c}+\int_0^t e^{(t-s)A}\m{f}(s) ds
  \]
  eikä muita ratkaisuja ole. Kun $e^{tA}$ tunnetaan, voidaan tämän nojalla selvittää vektori $\m{x}$ vakionvariointikaavan avulla. Integrointi ja sievennys on suoritettu käyttäen Maple-ohjelmistoa. Ratkaisuksi saadaan

  Sijoittamalla ratkaisuun $(t=0)$ saadaan vektori \textbf{c}, joten yhtälöryhmän ratkaisu on oikea. Alkuperäisen differentiaaliryhmän ratkaisut $x_1 -- x_6$ voidaan lukean edeltävän matriisin vastaavilta riveiltä. Ratkaisun stabiiliutta voidaan tarkastella niin kutsutun Lyapunovin lauseen avulla. Sen nojalla yhtälöryhmän ratkaisu on stabiili mikäli kerroinmatriisien kaikkien ominaisarvojen reaaliosat ovat negatiivisia. Koska $(\RE(\lambda_{3,4,5,6})=8)$, ratkaisu ei ole stabiili.

  \end{document}
  ```

Comment: Consecutive `displaymath` (or `\[...\]`) environments should be avoided; it's better to use `gather*` in this case, possibly with `\displaybreak` in suitable spots. Also it's dubious that `\[` comes just after an empty line.